# WHM / Rearrange an Account

Tags: centos, storage, cpanel

I recently bought another block of storage from my provider and following their guide, I rearranged my accounts to it:

1. `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/vdb`
2. `sudo mkdir /mnt/vol-us-1`
3. `sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/vdb /mnt/vol-us-1`
4. `bin/bash -c "if [ $(cat /etc/fstab | grep -i /dev/vdb | awk '{print $1}')!="/dev/vdb" ]; then sudo bash -c 'echo \/dev/vdb /mnt/vol-us-1 ext4 defaults,nofail,discard,noatime 1 2\ >> /etc/fstab';fi"`

This worked initially, but then I ran through an upgrade for WHM and I lost my settings, and the storage block seemed to have been wiped.  I was able to recover from a backup, but not entirely.

***I can see in my Disk Usage report that the mount exists:***
[image]

***But then trying to move my account, WHM doesn't let me do it:***

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

In WHM, by default all directories matching the "Home Directory Prefix" are checked for available disk space, and the instructions given by my provider don't consider the need to rearrange accounts, it's simply for adding a new disk.  So, I had to update my commands a bit to have WHM recognize the new disk as a location for accounts. I forgot about this change from the first time I did it.

1. `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/vdb`
2. `sudo mkdir /mnt/home`
3. `sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/vdb /mnt/home`
4. `bin/bash -c "if [ $(cat /etc/fstab | grep -i /dev/vdb | awk '{print $1}')!="/dev/vdb" ]; then sudo bash -c 'echo \/dev/vdb /mnt/home ext4 defaults,nofail,discard,noatime 1 2\ >> /etc/fstab';fi"`